# Reduce a while-loop condition - python

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to create a constraint so that the "lettera" input variable is a letter of the alphabet between a and h on this code *1 but I think there's a better way to write the condition for the loop.

Thanks if someone could help me figuring out how re-write it smaller.

*1

```
while (lettera != 'a' and lettera != 'b' and lettera != 'c' and lettera != 'd' and lettera != 'e' and lettera != 'f' and lettera != 'g' and lettera != 'h'):
    lettera= input('Inserisci un valore lettera a-h ')
```

Comment: [Please do not post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557); include the code as text instead.

Comment: `while lettera not in {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'}:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while lettera not in 'abcdefgh':
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the user enters an empty string`''` (e.g. by pressing enter). To fix this, you could check if the string is not blank e.g. `(lettera == '') or (lettera not in 'abcdefgh')` or use @gajendragarg's method of converting the string into a list `lettera not in list('abcdefgh')`

Comment: @honk, I deleted my comment. But you could see my comment. 

Comment: @gajendragarg I saw it just before it disappeared. Don't worry, it's definitely gone now!

Comment: @honk, got it! :)

Comment: @gajendragarg Why did you delete it tho?

Answer (score 0):

you could use python's `ord()` function to get the ascii code of a letter / character and check against a range, a-h are 97-104.

Answer (score 0):

```
lettera= input('Inserisci un valore lettera a-h ')
ttt = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
b = all([x != lettera for x in ttt])
while b:
    print(b)
```

Creating a list(ttt) of the necessary letters.
Creating a list in the list generator in which the values are True or False.

```
[x != lettera for x in ttt]
```

We apply the all function to it (if there is at least one False value, it will return False.

Comment: Hi, can you pelase update your answer to include an explanation about how it works and how does is solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

> constraint ... is a letter of the alphabet between a and h

Direct translation to Python would be

```py
letter_a = ...
while not 'a' <= letter_a <= 'h':
    letter_a = read("Please try again: ")
```

This would make it easy to raise `'h'` to e.g. `'n'`. If any letter could be added, the answer from @yzhang is more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

```
flag=True
while (flag):
    lettera=input()
    ascii_val = ord(lettera)
    print(ascii_val)
    if ((ascii_val>=97) and (ascii_val<=104)):
        flag=False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` function to filter from input

```
lettera= filter(lambda x: x not in "abcdefgh ", input('Inserisci un valore lettera a-h '))

print(*lettera)
```